# Swift - 'AnyObject!' is not convertible to 'ViewController'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I just updated my xcode from 6.2 to 6.3.1. The problem is I got a lot of this error message inside my project.

> /Users/MNurdin/Documents/iOS/xxxxx/Controllers/Profile/DirectoryTableViewController.swift:31:98:
>   'AnyObject!' is not convertible to 'ViewController'; did you mean to
>   use 'as!' to force downcast?

One of my code that affected with this error message.

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
            let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginView") as! ViewController
            self.presentViewController(viewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: With the new Swift 1.2 you should use if let to convert a viewController

Comment: The compiler tells you exactly how to solve the problem. There is even a "Convert to latest Swift syntax" option in Xcode. And it's all documented in the Xcode 6.3 release notes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After updating to Xcode 6.3, you are now using Swift 1.2

Prior to Swift 1.2, `as` was also used for forced conversion.

Swift 1.2 now represents forced conversions with `as!` to make it clear that the conversion may fail if you attempt to downcast to a type that doesn’t actually represent the value’s type.

So you have to use `as!` instead of `as`